# spring-boot-starter-freemarker dynamic looping example

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

Hi Can anyone help me on how I can use loop inside ftl file when using spring-boot-starter-freemarker, if I pass a dynamic array I should be able to print that in table,

```
</table>
</thead>
                <tbody>
                <#list ObjectList as list>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${list.firstname}</td>
                        <td>${list.lastname}</td>
                    </tr>
                </#list>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Here I am specifically setting the column if the fields increases every time I should update this ftl file with the new column, please let me know dymanic way of looping so that it takes how much ever columns I add

Comment: Don't call the items of a list `list`... it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I will pretend that you have `<#list objects as object>` in your example, as those variable names are easier to understand. You can list the subvariables (like `firstName`) inside an object like `<#list object?values as value><td>${value}</td></#list>`, but there will be problems with it, like you will list the class of the object as well (since there's a `object.getClass()` method), and you might list values that aren't directly printable (like a methods, that you will have to filter out with `?is_method`). So maybe the object that stands for that table (`objects`) should provide a list of column names, and then you have better control over what's displayed: `<#list objects.columnNames as columnName><td>${object[columnName]}</td></#list>`. You certainly will need to get the header names from somewhere too anyway, so some kind of metadata will have to come from somewhere. Also, with custom `ObjectWrapper` (configuration setting) you might as well use annotations to mark the getters you want, but that's a more advanced topic.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I tried the way you mentioned but I am getting exception, can you please let me know where I am missing wrong.               
                        <table>
    <thead>
     <tr bgcolor="#99a7cc">
         <#list objects.columnNames  as columnName>
      <th><b>${promo[columnName]}</b></th>
     </tr>
    </#list>     
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <#list objects.body as data>
     <tr>
      <td>${objects[data]}</td>
     </tr>
     </#list>     
    </tbody>
   </table>

Comment: @sinchanam Instead of `objects[data]` it should be `object[columnName]`, and you have to put that into a `#list`-ing of the `columnNames`.

Comment: Caused by: freemarker.core.NonExtendedHashException: For "?values" left-hand operand: Expected an extended hash, but this has evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence):
==> object.columnNames  [in template "sample.ftl" at line 44, column 63]

Comment: @sinchanam There's no `?values` in the failing template snippet that you have provided.

Comment: this is how I have tried                                                             
                      <table>
    <thead>
        <#list objects as object>
     <tr bgcolor="#99a7cc">
      <th><b><#list object.columnNames?values as value><td>${value}</td></#list></b></th>
     </tr>
     </#list>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <#list objects as object>
     <tr>
      <th><b><#list object.body?values as value><td>${value}</td></#list></b></th>
     </tr>
     </#list>
    </tbody>
   </table>

Comment: also can you please brief your comment "it should be object[columnName], and you have to put that into a #list-ing of the columnNames" ?

Comment: yeah that exception I got for the latest snippet that I have shared above

Comment: To clarify, the point of using `columnNames` and `object[columnName]` was exactly to avoid `?values` for a generic object.  `?values` is mostly only useful for `java.util.Map`-s, not for generic objects.